# Post works when run in python interpreter but gets AttributeError when saved as .py

Tags: python, post, python-requests, mailgun, attributeerror

I created a simple mailing app as a notification. When tested using python interpreter it works flawlessly. But if I run it as a stand alone application (.py) it says AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute 'post'.

```
import requests

def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://...",
        auth=("api", "key"),
        data={"from": "from",
              "to": "to",
              "subject": "Hello World",
              "text": "Text"})

send_simple_message()
```

It also creates a unusual folder in the directory

```
___pycache___
```

The error I receive is:

```
AttributeError: module 'requests' has no attribute post
```

The weird thing is the code is able to send the post without any errors when run on interpreter.

Comment: Can you post the error message?

Comment: @rukhta Posted the error. Do you think its a bug?

Comment: whats your filename, this error occurs when your file name equal to module name, for example: `requests.py`, if so change the filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs when your file name is same as the module name,

for example naming your file to `requests.py` will cause this error

so to avoid that you have to change its name to anything other than `requests.py`

Comment: Be sure to delete a requests.pyc if it exists, too.

Comment: I didn't create a requests.py file, but I did name it email.py and deleting that worked. Thanks.